# table1.date1 = get prior 12 months data from date1 in table2.monthyear in Athena? how to get 12 months prior data in year month?

Tags: sql, amazon-emr, amazon-athena, dbeaver

```
select 
   amt1,
   amt2 
from table2 
inner join table1 on table1.field1 = table2.field2 
        and table2.month_year between (substring(table1.date1,1,6) -12 month)
```

Comment: If you say so.  In my experience, queries start with a `SELECT` and have a `FROM` clause to indicate where the data comes from.

Comment: I am newbie and not sure correct syntax of the query, if anyone can help....@gordon Linoff

Comment: More information is needed to help you. Can you please provide us with the table structure for table1 and table2 and also explain how the data in them are related?

Are you trying to join rows in the two tables together, or are you pulling a single date value from table1 and using that to make the criteria for selecting rows from table2?

Comment: @NickFotopoulos, It is 4 tables join. I need to get date1 from table1 inner join on FIELD1 to get sum of amounts for 12 months from table2. Table 2 doesn't have date but it has Month_year field which you will get 12 months from. select amt1, amt2 from table 2 inner join table1 on table1.field1 = table 2.field2 where TABLE1.SUBSTRING(DATE1,1,6) = TABLE2.month_year and date1 -12 month. not sure how to write correct syntax

Comment: Okay, you basically just repeated what was in the original post. Without more details we cannot help you.

Comment: @NickFotopoulos, I want to enter 2nd row but hit add comment. I have provide more details.i am not sure how to write correct syntx table 1 has field 1, date1. table2 has field1 where you can inner join. amt1, amt2, month_year. We need to compare date1 from table 1 to get 12 months of data from table2

Comment: I'm assuming table2.month_year is char/varchar with 6 characters MMYYYY?
What about table1.Date1? Is it a datetime or a varchar in the form of DDMMYYYY?

Comment: @Dee: " It is 4 tables join" ???? I only see 2 tables (named: `table1` and `table2`).   Please add the table stricture of the table you use.

Comment: The [BETWEEN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) syntax you use is wrong. (see the link under BETWEEN)

Comment: @Luuk, do you know what will be correct syntax to use?

Comment: @Luuk, I need data from table4 and need to get 12 months data from table1. other 2 tables are just for joining with correct keys.....how to get 12 months data from date field and compare to month)year  ? I am trying to copy paste table structure but not sure it is showing correctly .                                                                     table1  table2 table3 table4 
field1 string field2 filed4 field6 varchar(60)
month_year varchar(255) field3 field5 field7 Varchar(50)
amt1 decimal(18,2) field8  date1 date
amt2 decimal(18,2)

Comment: @NickFotopoulos, month_year is varchar(255), yyyymm, 202105 and date1 is date data type and is showing in table as yyyy-mm-dd, 2021-05-20

Comment: I you want to show the table structure, you should use [edit] to add that info to your question.  (The `edit` is also in the list  `Share Edit Follow Close Flag` directly below the question)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    amt1,
    amt2
FROM    Table2      AS t2
INNER JOIN Table1 AS t1
    ON t1.Field1 = t2.Field2
    AND SUBSTRING(t1.DATE1, 1, 6) BETWEEN LEFT(t2.month_year, 4) + CAST(CAST(RIGHT(t2.month_year, 2) AS int) - 12 AS varchar(2)) AND t2.month_year;
```